# Safe way to get the post ID in the_title()

Tags: get-the-title

Is there a safe way to get the post ID inside `the_title()`?

```
add_filter('the_title', "change_post_title");

function change_post_title($title){

}
```

I tried using `global $post` and `get_the_ID()`, but this won't work in some cases (e.g. on a single page where `the_title()` is being called inside the navigation to link to the next post. `global $post` and `get_the_ID()` will reference the single post instead of the post that is being linked to.)

With `get_page_by_title()` I'd have to spawn multiple queries to cover all post types.

Do I have to fall back to a custom query?

Answer (score 1):

Some filters in Wordpress are just not user friendly and does not always quite do what one wants to.

`the_title` filter will apply changes to all instances of `get_the_title()` (which is used by `the_title()`). So widget titles, related posts titles and post link titles are all changed, which is a problem when you just need to target the main post on a single page for instance

I have recently bumped into [this post](http://joshlevinson.me/wordpress/filter-a-page-posts-title-only-on-that-page-post/) by Josh Levinson on his blog while having the same issue. He suggested to make use of the `loop_start` action where you check whether or not you are in the main query, and if you are, apply your `the_title` filter. If the query is not the main query, simply remove the filter

I have made a few changes to the original code. Just a note, you need php 5.3+ as closures was only introduced in php 5.3

```
add_action('loop_start', function ($q)
{
    if($q->is_main_query()){
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'modified_post_title', 10, 2);
    }else{
        remove_filter('the_title','modified_post_title', 10, 2);
    }
});
function modified_post_title($title)
{
    global $post;
    ?><pre><?php var_dump($post->ID); ?></pre><?php 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, however, If I call e.g. `next_post_link()` on a content-single page the filter is also applied to the `the_title()` call from `next_post_link()`

Comment: I've tested this on twentyfourteen, and cannot replicate your problem